# How to redirect a custom environment variable to Window's %HOMEPATH%

Tags: windows, windows-8, environment-variables

On Linux, you can obtain the path of the home directoy via `HOME`, in Windows via `HOMEPATH`. I'd like to create a custom environment variable in Windows called `HOME` that "redirects" to `HOMEPATH`.

The reason for this is a script that basically runs on both Windows and Linux. The only problem is that it looks for an environment variable called `HOME` to find the home directory. This obviously works on Linux, but not on Windows, thus I thought it might work if I create a "Dummy-Home" variable on Windows.

I added the following entry to the environment variable dialog: `key: HOME, value: %HOMEPATH%`.
Unfortunately it seems that %HOMEPATH% does not get evaluated although it is available in the command line.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Is the Window script a batch script?

Comment: no, it's a logback configuration file (for a Java logger) that uses   `${HOME}`, means it looks for an environemnt variable called home. As mentioned, home is available on linux but not on windows per default.

Comment: You may want to test first: If you make a %HOME% variable in Windows and point it to the actual path you want to use, does it work as expected (with the software in question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

1. Start `regedit.exe`, and navigate to:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
   ```
2. Right-click the empty area in the right pane and select **New > Expandable String Value** from the context menu.
3. Name the new value `HOME`. Double-click it and change it's data to `%HOMEPATH%`.
4. Log off and log back on to apply the changes.

**Note** Keep in mind the `%HOMEPATH%` variable is missing the drive letter from the path, so you might want to set the `HOME` value to `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` instead. Alternatively you could use `%USERPROFILE%` too.